# What does .html() mean?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What does the method `.html()` mean in the javascript library `d3.js`? I'm reading up on how to uses tooltips on graphs in `d3.js` and I came across the following:

```
.html(function(d) { return d; })
```

Can someone please explain this to me please?

Comment: [The docs are your friend.](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#html)

Answer (score 1):

The `.html` function either sets or gets `html` on an element.  In this case, you're returning `d` from an anonymous function, which means that you've bound data to an element, and that data is being passed down as a parameter `d` into your anonymous function.  That function returns `d`, so that means that when you call

```
.html(function(d){return d;})
```

you're really just doing this:

```
.html(d)
```

Since `d` is your data, it's setting the `html` of the element to the value of `d`.